# Sending big packets gets Bad Address error

Tags: c, ffmpeg, send

Im writing a live webcam stream using ffmpeg and sdl on C. 
my platform is linux.

my application is a client server based. 
The client is reading from the webcam, produce an AVPacket, then send to server.

My problem is, that the AVPacket struct has a member named data which is approximately 600k.
At first, i had not checked the send() return value, 
So, of course the packet had failed to send completely.

But after I checked, the send() returns Bad Address error at the second iteration of the big packet. 
the length of the data packet must be correct because is supplied from the AVPacket struct.

It sends 2 members of the AVPacket before, so the server is up and functional.

The problematic section:

```
    int send_video_data(video_client_t *client, void* buf, int length)
    {
        int rc;

        while (length > 0)
        {
           if ((rc = send(client->sockfd, buf, length, 0)) == -1) {
                     perror("failed sending data to server");
                     exit(1);
            }

            length-=rc;
            buf+=rc;
        }

        return 0;

    }
```

Any one got any ideas why it's not working? 
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out. 
The problem was with the AVPacket.

somehow, the size was not correct (maby beacuse video for linux) 
So i decode the packet and encode it back again and it is working now.